# Cannot open XML files in Graphical Layout: FakeAdapter cannot be cast to BaseAdapter

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm having some problems with my android project in eclipse.

I have two XML layout files, and both contain ListViews.

The ListViews are working perfectly on my Android phone, but eclipse wont open the design window, giving the following error:

```
com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.binding.FakeAdapter cannot be cast to android.widget.BaseAdapter
```

Both files contains the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/cardList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fadeScrollbars="true"
    android:fastScrollAlwaysVisible="true"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
    android:scrollbarSize="30dp"
    android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay" >
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: That would appear to be a bug in the ADT plugin for Eclipse. Make sure you are on the current version of ADT and the SDK developer tools.

Comment: Remove `android:fastScrollEnabled="true"` and `android:fastScrollEnabled="true"`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It might be the

```
android:fastScrollAlwaysVisible="true"
```

that is bugging your application. Try deleting it.

Comment: What is the reason behind this? can you explain.?

Comment: I cannot, no. It is one of those things that I just figured out by trial-and-error.

Answer (score 1):

Just change device in layout preview.

Small screens (inches < 7) cannot preview properly. Select 10.1'' for example.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any android:fastScroll* option in any of my layouts, however I do receive this error on any version of Android, but can't reproduce on any test devices.

Turns out this occurs when I attach an Adapter declared like this:

```
MyAdapter implements ListAdapter
```

Changing to the following actually fixes the issue:

```
MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter
```

EDIT: Turns out users where using an Xposed module to forst fastscroll on app ListView's! Unfortunately that module is pretty dumb and doesn't check the adapter type.